# Get-Service from Variable

Tags: powershell, variables

I want a user input for `Get-Service` but it is not accepting my variable

I want to run the following command:

```
#### --- Content -- ### 
# - Location ##
$Service_text   = "$env:userprofile\documents\PS-Script-Services\Services.txt"

#- Test path
$service_test = Test-Path $Service_text

#-- Get-content ##-
$Get_the_service = Get-Content $service_text

#-loop-# -- Get-Service -- ##
if ($service_test -eq $false) {
  Write-Host "To view your Services go to Start --> en typ services, or go to Powershell and type get-service"
  Write-Host "Which Services do you want to monitor? (Example: Teamviewer, BITS, DHCP, Eventlog, Spooler."  -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow
  Write-Host "This script only works when a service has been stopped" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Yellow
  Read-Host "Enter services" | Out-File $service_text
  $ask_service = Get-Service -Name $Get_the_service
```

The problem is that it can't get the service(s).

```
$Service_name  = "dhcp"

Get-Service -Name $service_name
```

gives me this output:

```
Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Running  dhcp               DHCP Client
```

but if I want multiple services

```
$Service_name  = "dhcp, spooler"

Get-Service -Name $service_name
```

I' getting this error:

```
Get-Service : Cannot find any service with service name 'dhcp, spooler'.
At line:5 char:1
+ Get-Service -Name $service_name
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dhcp, spooler:String) [Get-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoServiceFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no service with the name `dhcp, spooler`. Apparently you're trying to get a list of services (namely `dhcp` and `spooler`). For that you must define `$Service_name` as an actual list, not as a single string with comma-separated words:

```
$Service_name = "dhcp", "spooler"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass an array to the `Get-Service`cmdlet if you want to retrieve multiple services. You could use `-split` to split your string into an array and Trim any whitespaces:

```
Get-Service -Name ($Service_name -split ',' | % { $_.Trim() } )
```

Answer (score 0):

"dhcp, spooler" is a literal string. So when you pass it to get-service, Get-Service looks for a service called *dhcp, spooler*. Instead, pass it a 'list' of strings separated by commas. i.e. 'dhcp','spooler'
Then you can pass it as many as you like.
If you're collecting the names from a text file, make sure each service is on a new line